# How to get subscribers count using Facebook API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to get the subscribers count from a profile? I have been looking around at the version 2.2 api but couldn't find an option for that.

Answer (score 1):

With a valid access token, `https://graph.facebook.com/me/subscribers` responds with something like:

```
{
  "data": [
  ], 
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 29
  }
}
```

Comment: `/subscribers` endpoint is deprecated in 2.0, won't work after 30.04.2015.